# How can I get the result of geolocation

Tags: geolocation

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` requires three parameters success, fail and options.

What I want to get is the result of position. I have try return the position by success function, but it returns 'undefined'

```
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
  return pos;
};
pos = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
console.log('pos', pos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getCurrentPosition returns the Position object back in the success handler

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

if you wanted to refer to position later on the only way would be storing it in a global variable and using it later. Just remember the global will not be initialised until after the success callback.

```
 var g_pos;

 function error(e){
  alert(e);
 }

 function success(pos) {
   var crd = pos.coords;
   g_pos = pos; // assign to global
   console.log('Your current position is:');
   console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
   console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
   console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
   return pos;
 };

 var options = {
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 5000,
   maximumAge: 0
 };

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

 //hint type g_pos in console after and you can see the position object.
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, how can I catch the call back immediately? The only solution I can think of is using the a function to catch the call. I have a  program based on the pos variable; hard to know if it is successfuly call or error call.